# Rails 4 - STI has_many :through with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, sti

I'm have an issue trying to combine Rails 4, STI, polymorphic associations with has_many: :through

The issue: UserConnection is not saving the correct userable_type according to the STI

```
class UserConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_connections
  has_many :tagged_posts, through: :user_connections, class_name: 'Post', source: :userable, source_type: 'Post'
end

class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_connections, as: :userable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_connections
end

class Post < Publication
end

Post.create(user_ids: [1, 2], body: 'yo')
UserConnection.last
=> #<UserConnection id: 1, user_id: 2, userable_id: 44, userable_type: "Publication">
```

userable_type should be "Post" but it's "Publication".

I tried adding the following according to all the similar StackOverflow questions:

```
class UserConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  def userable_type=(class_name)
     super(class_name.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end
```

This didn't help.

Any ideas will greatly appreciated

Comment: does `User` have other `UserConnection` that aren't in the inheritance tree of `Publication`? maybe the polymorphic `userable` isn't needed here.

Comment: yes. UserConnection is meant to be used with other classes besides publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out it's an old issue that wasn't solved yet

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/724

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6786

gem patch solution:
https://github.com/appfolio/store_base_sti_class

tested it with your code and it works.